# Retina display VS normal display color difference

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, uibutton, retina-display

I am designing a custom button with that requires me to overlay a `UIButton` on top of a `UIImageView`. The `UIImageView` uses a `[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:]` image and the `UIButton` has a background color with a pattern image `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonPattern.png"]]`

The problem I am facing is that on iPhone 4, the images from the `UIButton` and the `UIImageView` appear to have slightly different colors although they should match. Testing the same thing on an iPhone 3GS shows normal results without the color difference.

This image shows the difference:

[image]

as you can see it looks fine on the 3GS. On the retina display you can clearly see the difference in color. I even tried using the low res images (from the 3GS) on the retina display, the colors were still showing differently. is this a bug in retina display devices? has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Do you two different images for the stretchableImage? And if so, is the @2x one exactly 2x larger than the other one?

Comment: yes the '@2x' image is exactly 2x larger. I also tried removing the '@2x' images and using the regular ones just to see what happens. It didn't fix it.

Comment: How did you create all of the different images?  Did you use Photoshop (or any other Adobe program)?  Did you disable color management?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have to overlay the button over a UIImageView? Why can't you just retire the imageview and use the image property of the custom button? Regardless, can you share the image(s) with us (and if you're manually setting any colors for your backgrounds, what colors are you using), as that's a lot easier to diagnose than the problem in the abstract. If there's something proprietary about the image, just redact that part if you need to.

Comment: @robmayoff yes i was using adobe illustrator with disabled color management. The exported png's match if you place them next to each other so thats not the problem. Also, if you look at the 3gs image above, it works perfectly as you cannot tell where the image cuts off.

Comment: @RobertRyan I understand it would be much simpler using the UIButton image property. Unfortunately for this specific design, the button needs to be stretchable and it uses a grainy texture as you can see and it also has rounded corners. So i had to combine both a stretchable image with a patterned image. perhaps you know another way of achieving the same results?

Comment: @robmayoff you were right. I had adjusted the image with pixelmator and turns out pixelmator was applying an RGB profile to the image and i guess the retina display draws the profile differently. I removed the profile and it works perfectly now! if you'd like to write that as an answer so i can accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure none of your image files has an embedded color profile.  This can be tricky.  For Adobe software, this page is helpful:

http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/

Comment: Rather than retina vs. non-retina, perhaps different iOS versions treat color profiles differently. Happens with web browsers a lot!