# UIColor, iPhone 5 vs iPhone 4

Tags: ios, photoshop, uicolor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retina display VS normal display color difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059797/retina-display-vs-normal-display-color-difference)

My designer has provided me with an iPhone app design using photoshop.

The colours work great on the simulator and iMac monitor.

But as soon as those designs get to the device, everything looks off.
I know/am told this has something to with how the iPhone displays colour.

What I think I have to do is find a colour that works on the device using something like LiveView.

The problem is, the colours are perfect on the iPhone5. But for every other device, they are off. Do I have to pick and choose a colour for each device?

Is this a common problem with colours on the iPhone? Or just some colours?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you ever find a solution>?

Comment: No I didn't. I thought it might just be my iPhone 3GS in the end, because people with the 3GS device were reporting that the colours looked fine, so a problem with my device's screen made sense.

Comment: It seems like the problem isn't fixable and is just a problem with the displays. I literally tried everything and in the end it seems just have to live with it. The 3GS, 4, and 4S were all off for me, but the 5 displays the colors perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Colors will appear differently on any screen - there are some wonderful tools like [XScope](http://iconfactory.com/software/xscope) that you and your visual designer should be using to preview visual designs on-device while designing in Photoshop.

If your designer is comparing what's on their laptop to what's in your coded app, then they're doing it wrong: they need a way to preview their PSDs on-device as they work. What you see on your iMac won't match what you'll see on-device.

In addition, Panic's made a wonderful color picker tool that you should look at. It plugs into OS X's standard color picker, but gives you the ability to generate UIColor code. You can find the tool here: http://panic.com/~wade/picker/

Comment: Thanks. I'll check those out.