# Xcode render different color

Tags: ios, xcode, photoshop

I create a design for my new app. I decide to create the Launch Screen with Auto-layout, half of the screen with a image and the rest with solid color.

When I copy the HEX & RGB values of the solid color (the same as the image) it renders different on the Xcode. why? I need to put it as code?

Image: the top color is the real and the bottom is the one it appears

If I compare the sRGB values for both color and I make

New Color on Xcode = Real Color + (Real Color - Render Color)

It works and looks fine but I don't know why it happened this, and if its correct my solution?

Best,

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your image doesn't have an embedded color profile?  See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11059797/77567) and [this page about disabling Photoshop's color management](http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too familiar with photoshop. Assuming you created the purple background in interface builder, it is effectively the same as creating the background programmatically.

How did you get the RBG -or- HEX colors in the first place? If you used something like a color picker, the color may have changed from the point you created it in photoshop to when you sampled it.

Is the image a JPG? If the image was converted to or from a lossy format, it may have changed slightly in color.

Comment: Hi scord, the real color (top) was crated on photoshop, exported on PNG (tested and same color in both formats psd, png) then I fill it it with color created with XCODE interfase Builder (no code), and it's different. I always use sRGB + PNG formats. I use three different picker colors: Apple built in (Digital color meter), Photoshop, and XCODE color picker