# why the CGImageGetBytesPerRow() method return a weird value on some images?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I got an image from a bigger image by

```
let partialCGImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(CGImage, frame)
```

but sometimes I got wrong RGBA value. For example, I calculated the average red values of an image, but it turned out like a gray image.
So I checked the info as follow.

```
image width: 64
image height: 64
image has 5120 bytes per row
image has 8 bits per component
image color space: <CGColorSpace 0x15d68fbd0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
image is mask: false
image bitmap info: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: 8194)
image has 32 bits per pixel
image utt type: nil
image should interpolate: true
image  rendering intent: CGColorRenderingIntent
Bitamp Info: ------
Alpha info mask: Ture
Float components: False
Byte oder mask: Ture
Byte order default: False
Byte order 16 little: False
Byte order 32 little: Ture
Byte order 16 big: Ture
Byte order 32 big: False
Image Info ended---------------
```

Then I got a really weird problem, why the width and height are both 64 pxs, and the image has 8 bits(1 byte) per component(4 bytes per pixel), but the bytes per row is 5120?
And I notice the bitmap info of the normal image is quite different, it doesn't has any byte order infomation.
I googled the different between little endian and big endian, but I got confused when they showed up together.
I really need help since my project has already delayed for 2 days because of that. Thanks!

By the way, I used following code to get the RGBA value.

```
let pixelData=CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage))
let data:UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

var rs: [[Int]] = []
var gs: [[Int]] = []
var bs: [[Int]] = []

let widthMax = imageWidth
let heightMax = imageHeight
for indexX in 0...widthMax {
        var tempR: [Int] = []
        var tempG: [Int] = []
        var tempB: [Int] = []
        for indexY in 0...heightMax {
            let offSet = 4 * (indexX * imageWidth + indexY)
            **let r = Int(data[pixelInfo + offSet])
            let g = Int(data[pixelInfo + 1 + offSet])
            let b = Int(data[pixelInfo + 2 + offSet])**
            tempR.append(r)
            tempG.append(g)
            tempB.append(b)
        }
        rs.append(tempR)
        gs.append(tempG)
        bs.append(tempB)
    }
```

Ask me if you have problem with my code. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the question about `pixelInfo`, raised by Segmentation, the calculation of `offSet` seem curious:

```
let offSet = 4 * (indexX * imageWidth + indexY)
```

The `x` and `y` values are backwards. Also, you also cannot assume that the bytes per row is always equal to 4 times the width in pixels because some image formats pad bytes per row. Anyway, it theoretically it should be:

```
let offSet = indexY * bytesPerRow + indexX * bytesPerPixel
```

Also note that in addition to the x/y flip issue, you don't want `0 ... widthMax` and `0 ... heightMax` (as those will return `widthMax + 1` and `heightMax + 1` data points). Instead, you want to use `0 ..< widthMax` and `0 ..< heightMax`.

Also if you're dealing with random image files, there are other deeper problems here. For example, you can't make assumptions regarding RGBA vs ARGB vs CMYK, big endian vs little endian, etc., captured in the bitmap info field.

Rather than writing code that can deal with all of these variations in pixel buffers, Apple suggests alternative to take the image of some random configuration and render it to some consistent context configuration, and then you can navigate the buffer more easily. See [Technical Q&A #1509](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1509/_index.html).

Comment: Thanks you very much! I tried method you mentioned and it did work!

Comment: But it still has one problem, I create a 2448 * 2222 jpeg image and set all the pixels' RGB color to (238, 42, 43) without alpha channel in Photoshop. But it turns out (231, 17, 33) in my app. In addition, I use following algorithm to calculate the average RGB value.  `func averageOfdata(Array data: [[Int]] ) -> Int{
        var resultInTotal: Int = 0
        var count: Int = 0
        
        for valueArray in data {
            for value in valueArray {
                count += 1
                resultInTotal += value
            }
        }
        return Int(resultInTotal / count)
    }
`

Comment: Ask me if you have any question, thanks for your help!

Comment: Well,  the `X` and `Y` value did backward, thank you.

Comment: @CallOfOrange - Re the color issue, I just created an image in Photoshop with 238, 42, 43 and when I processed it like shown above, in my app I saw 238, 42, 43. I suspect that there's some colorspace inconsistency or something like that. I'd first open up the JPG again, and confirm that the values weren't altered in the export process or something like that.

Comment: @CallOfOrange - Re the `averageOfData`, I'm not sure of your intent there, but you're averaging all of the reds, greens, and blues together. Personally, I always do luminance calculations, e.g. `let luminance = 0.2126 * red + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance. So I might do that for every pixel, and then average those values.

Comment: I checked the image with another software. The color is 231, 17, 33. I guess there's some color space problems just as you said. Thanks.

Comment: I develop this app for chemical detection, the averages of all the reds, greens and blues are all I need. So, I think the luminance is not necessary for me this time. It wouldn't influence the RGB value, right?

Answer (score 4):

The bytes-per-row is 5120 because you used `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` on a larger image. [From the `CGImage` reference manual](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithImageInRect):

> The resulting image retains a reference to the original image, which means you may release the original image after calling this function.

The new image uses the same pixel storage as the old (larger) image. That's why the new image retains the old image, and why they have the same bytes-per-row.

As for why you're not getting the red values you expect: Rob's answer has some useful information, but if you want to explore deeper, consider that your bitmap info is 8194 = 0x2002.

```
print(CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)

# Output:
8194
```

These bits determine the byte order of your bitmap. But those names aren't all that helpful. Let's figure out exactly what byte order we get for those bits:

```
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, 1, 1, 8, 4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)!
UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
let d: CGFloat = 255
UIColor(red: 1/d, green: 2/d, blue: 3/d, alpha: 1).setFill()
UIRectFill(.infinite)
UIGraphicsPopContext()
let data = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(CGBitmapContextGetData(context))
for i in 0 ..< 4 {
    print("\(i): \(data[i])")
}

# Output:
0: 3
1: 2
2: 1
3: 255
```

So we can see that a bitmap info of 8194 means that the byte order is BGRA. Your code assumes it's RGBA.

Comment: It helps me totally understand where my bug is. Thanks for your help and such detailed example.  I really want to say some better words to thanks you and Rob, but my English don't allow me to that.  If convenient

Comment: Please give me some advice about the problem I mentioned on Rob's comment if it's convenient for you and Rob.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11065716/77567) and the linked article.

Comment: Thank you for your article, it helps me a lot. 

Comment: Info on the BGRA ordering was very helpful!!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you haven't initialize `pixelInfo` variable. Second you aren't doing anything with the `A` value shifting everything 8bits to the left. Also i don't think you need `pixelInfo` and `offset`, these two variables are the same so keep one of them equal to what you wrote for `offset`

Comment: Sorry, I just posted a part of the code and I forgot to post that part of code. I initialized `pixelInfor` at the begining of the function. I thought it would be tired to read too much code, so I picked the important part. I will post all of it and comment the important part next time. Thank you for help.